# Awaiting completed tasks in async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

When we call an async method we get a wrapper task returned.

```
public async Task ExecuteActionAsync() {
  // no await called
}
public async Task ExecuteActionAwaitAsync() {
  // await called on a completed
  await Task.CompletedTask;
}
public async Task MyMethod(){
  await ExecuteActionAsync();
  await ExecuteActionAwaitAsync();
}
```

If I never use the `await` keyword within a function (`ExecuteActionAsync`) or all tasks awaited in a function (`ExecuteActionAwaitAsync`) are already completed by the time we await them, do I have a guarantee that the task returned by calling these methods will be in the completed state? And recursively, the task returned by `MyMethod` will also be in the completed state as it meets the criteria mentioned earlier (awaiting completed tasks). I believe I read about an optimization which handles this situation, but I cannot find it anywhere right now.

Bonus question: does calling `Task.WhenAll` on completed tasks return a completed task?

Comment: Is it `ExecuteActionAwaitAsync` or `ExecuteAction2Async`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias my apologies, I renamed the method but missed the call, fixed it

Comment: Don't you get a warning for `ExecuteActionAsync()`?

Comment: @Tarik: yes, you get a warning that your method will run synchronously.

Comment: @Tarik the generated warning is not really relevant to the question I believe

Comment: Based on the C# specification linked and quoted in Johan Donne's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59338412/11178549) I would be pretty confident that awaiting a completed `Task` would always result in a `Task` in a completed state. But be aware of the `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` case. This flag [is not always honored](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can easily be tested:

```
        var t1 = ExecuteActionAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Returned task: {t1.IsCompleted}");
        await t1;
        Console.WriteLine($"Awaited task: {t1.IsCompleted}\n");

        var t2 = MyMethod();
        Console.WriteLine($"Returned task: {t2.IsCompleted}");
        await t2;
        Console.WriteLine($"Awaited task: {t2.IsCompleted}\n");

        t1 = ExecuteActionAsync();
        t2 = MyMethod();

        var t3 = Task.WhenAll(new []{t1,t2 });
        Console.WriteLine($"Task from WhenAll: {t3.IsCompleted}");
```

Result:

```
Returned task: True
Awaited task: True

Returned task: True
Awaited task: True

Task from WhenAll: True
```

So: Yes, if the async method runs synchronously, the returned Task is completed. And yes, the Task returned from WhenAll passing async methods that run synchronously is also completed.

Stephen Cleary wrote a usefull [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on this subject. Specifically the following quote is relevant:

> The beginning of an async method is executed just like any other method. That is, it runs synchronously until it hits an “await” (or throws an exception).
>
> The “await” keyword is where things can get asynchronous. Await is like a unary operator: it takes a single argument, an awaitable (an “awaitable” is an asynchronous operation). Await examines that awaitable to see if it has already completed; if the awaitable has already completed, then the method just continues running (synchronously, just like a regular method).

Approaching the question form the [specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#awaitable-expressions) side:

- an async method must return an 'awaitable' type (e.g. 'Task'), which must have an 'IsCompleted' property
- "the purpose of the IsCompleted property is to determine if the task is already complete. If so, there is no need to suspend evaluation."

From these statements, it can be concluded that an async method that runs synchronously, will indeed return a completed Task.

Even if an exception is thrown while executing the async method, the returned Task will be completed ('IsCompleted' will return 'true' though 'IsCompletedSuccessfully' will return 'false').

Comment: I'm somewhat skeptical using an example as a basis for certain design decisions I'm making. The behavior could very well be changed unless it's a part of the specs

Answer (score 0):

From experience, it's yes for all your questions, except for the empty `ExecuteActionAsync()` which should cause a warning and which empty body or in fact anything else that falls in its body that is not being awaited should execute synchronously.

Comment: Warning will indeed be generated, however, I'm curious about the task returned by calling the method. Do you believe it won't be in the completed state? It usually is, but I'd like to know whether that behavior is guaranteed by the runtime